# Windows 10 IoT Raspberry - VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-iot-core

I want to run the Windows 10 IoT([check here](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm)) Raspberry on VirtualBox.

I followed all steps explained [here](http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/running-windows-10-iot-core-in-a-virtual-machine/)

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine w10IoT.

Failed to open image 'G:\VM_Workstations\wIoTTest\kmdF41E.vhd' for writing due to wrong permissions (VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY).

Failed to attach driver below us! Image is read-only. (VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY).

AHCI: Failed to attach drive to Port0 (VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I tried for both MinnowBoardMax and also for Raspberry.

I have no Raspberry board, so help needed to run this on VirtualBox.

Comment: I just tried doing this with HyperV instead of Virtual Box. But sadly it didn't boot up either.

Comment: I've tried the same thing but ended up with just a shell prompt and now windows startup.